# limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}})$$

At first I wanted to write that $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}})=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\infty$$ but then I remembered that $sin$ is bounded.

Next I look at $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}})\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}})}{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}\cdot {e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}=1\cdot\infty =\infty$$

But it seems from the graph of the function that the limits are $\{-1,1\}$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}) \ne\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ because $e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ tends to infinity and not zero. I do not think this limit exists.

Comment: Yes but how can I show that the limits are -1 and 1?

Answer (score 5):

The limit doesn't exist. You can see it doesn't by finding sequences $\{x_n\}$ of positive numbers that converge to zero but such that $\sin (e^{1/x_n^2})$ converges to different numbers.

For instance, let 
$$
x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{\log n\pi}}.
$$
Then
$$
\sin e^{1/x_n^2}=\sin e^{\log n\pi}=\sin n\pi=0
$$
for all $n$. Or you can take 
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log \frac{(4n+1)\pi}2}},
$$
in which case
$$
\sin e^{1/x_n^2}=1
$$
for all $n$.

More generally, given any $r\in[-1,1]$ let $t$ such that $\sin t=r$. Then form 
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log (t+2n\pi)}},
$$
and we get a sequence with $x_n\to0$ and 
$$
\sin e^{1/x_n^2}=\sin t=r
$$
for all $n$. In other words, the function $\sin e^{1/x^2}$ takes all values from $[-1,1]$ in any interval of the form $(0,\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.